# Hidden forall quantified types in ReifiedTraversal

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, forall

This question really is more generic, since while I was asking it I found out how to fix it in this particular case (even though I don't like it) but I'll phrase it in my particular context.

**Context:**

I'm using the lens library and I found it particularly useful to provide functionality for "adding" traversals (conceptually, a traversal that traverses all the elements in both original traversals). I did not find a default implementation so I did it using `Monoid`. In order to be able to implement an instance, I had to use the `ReifiedTraversal` wrapper, which I assume is in the library precisely for this purpose:

```
-- Adding traversals
add_traversals :: Semigroup t => Traversal s t a b -> Traversal s t a b -> Traversal s t a b
add_traversals t1 t2 f s = liftA2 (<>) (t1 f s) (t2 f s)

instance Semigroup t => Semigroup (ReifiedTraversal s t a b) where
    a1 <> a2 = Traversal (add_traversals (runTraversal a1) (runTraversal a2))

instance Semigroup s => Monoid (ReifiedTraversal' s a) where
    mempty = Traversal (\_ -> pure . id)
```

The immediate application I want to extract from this is being able to provide a traversal for a specified set of indices in a list. Therefore, the underlying semigroup is `[]` and so is the underlying `Traversable`. First, I implemented a lens for an individual index in a list:

```
lens_idx :: Int -> Lens' [a] a
lens_idx _ f [] = error "No such index in the list"
lens_idx 0 f (x:xs) = fmap (\rx -> rx:xs) (f x)
lens_idx n f (x:xs) = fmap (\rxs -> x:rxs) (lens_idx (n-1) f xs)
```

All that remains to be done is to combine these two things, ideally to implement a function `traversal_idxs :: [Int] -> Traversal' [a] a`

**Problem:**

I get type checking errors when I try to use this. I know it has to do with the fact that `Traversal` is a type that includes a constrained `forall` quantifier in its definition. In order to be able to use the `Monoid` instance, I need to first reify the lenses provided by `lens_idx` (which are, of course, also traversals). I try to do this by doing:

```
r_lens_idx :: Int -> ReifiedTraversal' [a] a
r_lens_idx = Traversal . lens_idx
```

But this fails with two errors (two versions of the same error really):

```
Couldn't match type ‘f’ with ‘f0’...

Ambiguous type variable ‘f0’ arising from a use of ‘lens_idx’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Functor f0)’ from being solved...
```

I understand this has to do with the hidden `forall f. Functor f =>` in the `Traversal` definition. While writing this, I realized that the following does work:

```
r_lens_idx :: Int -> ReifiedTraversal' [a] a
r_lens_idx idx = Traversal (lens_idx idx)
```

So, by giving it the parameter it can make the `f` explicit to itself and then it can work with it. However, this feels extremely ad-hoc. Specially because originally I was trying to build this `r_lens_idx` inline in a where clause in the definition of the `traversal_idxs` function (in fact... on a function defining this function inline because I'm not really going to use it that often).

So, sure, I guess I can always use lambda abstraction, but... is this really the right way to deal with this? It feels like a hack, or rather, that the original error is an oversight by the type-checker.

Comment: I think that `ATraversal` is more suitable to your purposes. It doesn't have the `forall` so it avoids your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The "adding" of traversals that you want was added in the most recent lens release, you can find it under the name [adjoin](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-Unsound.html#v:adjoin). Note that it is unsound to use if your traversals overlap at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to my own question, although it is only pointing out that what I was trying to do with traversals was not actually possible in that shape and how I overcame it. **There is still** the underlying problem of the hidden forall quantified variables and how is it possible that lambda abstraction can make code that does not type check suddenly type check (or rather, why it did not type check to start with).

It turns out my implementation of `Monoid` for `Traversal` was deeply flawed. I realized when I started debugging it. For instance, I was trying to combine a list of indices, and a function that would return a lens for each index, mapping to that index in a list, to a traversal that would map to exactly those indices. That is possible, but it **relies on the fact that `List` is a `Monad`**, instead of just using the `Applicative` structure.

The function that I had written originally for `add_traversal` used only the `Applicative` structure, but instead of mapping to those indices in the list, it would duplicate the list for each index, concatenating them, each version of the list having applied its lens.

When trying to fix it, I realized I needed to use `bind` to implement what I really wanted, and then I stumbled upon this: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4tfao3/monadic_traversals/

So the answer was clear: I can do what I want, but it's not a `Monoid` over `Traversal`, but instead a `Monoid` over `MTraversal`. It still serves my purposes perfectly.

This is the resulting code for that:

```
-- Monadic traversals: Traversals that only work with monads, but they allow other things that rely on the fact they only need to work with monads, like sum.
type MTraversal s t a b = forall m. Monad m => (a -> m b) -> s -> m t
type MTraversal' s a = MTraversal s s a a

newtype ReifiedMTraversal s t a b = MTraversal {runMTraversal :: MTraversal s t a b}
type ReifiedMTraversal' s a = ReifiedMTraversal s s a a

-- Adding mtraversals
add_mtraversals :: Semigroup t => MTraversal r t a b -> MTraversal s r a b -> MTraversal s t a b
add_mtraversals t1 t2 f s = (t2 f s) >>= (t1 f)

instance Semigroup s => Semigroup (ReifiedMTraversal' s a) where
    a1 <> a2 = MTraversal (add_mtraversals (runMTraversal a1) (runMTraversal a2))

instance Semigroup s => Monoid (ReifiedMTraversal' s a) where
    mempty = MTraversal (\_ -> return . id)
```

Note that `MTraversal` is still a `LensLike` and an `ASetter`, so you can use many operators from the lens package, like `.~`.

As I mentioned, though, I still have to use lambda abstraction when using this for my purposes due to the forall quantifier being in an uncomfortable place, and I'd love if someone could clarify what the heck is up with the type checker in that regard.